# DNS delegation with BIND and Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, cloudflare

probably just an ordinary question, but I've been wasting hours on this for months.
If you need other logs/output/explanation/etc. just ask :)

Thanks in advance!

### What I need

- The zone `local.example.com` shall be managed by a local server `10.20.0.9`
- The local servers (10.20.0.0/24) are only accessible from within the network **but**
- Their hostnames `xxx.local.example.com` are resolvable world-wide from the internet

### What I have so far

I am using CloudFlare as DNS provider, following [this guide](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021357131-Delegating-Subdomains-Outside-of-Cloudflare), I have set-up the following:

- Records at CloudFlare:

  ```
  ns.example.com   A   10.20.0.9       (local DNS server)
  loc.example.com  NS  ns.example.com  (delegation to local DNS)
  ```
- Records file at my local DNS server (`10.20.0.9` using bind9)

  ```
  loc.example.com. IN SOA ns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
      1628517915
      3600
      600
      24H
      3600 )
  s1.loc.example.com.  IN A 10.20.0.9
  ```

### My Problem

CloudFlare does not answer my NS lookup request for `loc.example.com` with `ns.example.com` as expected. Instead, the request just failes with "server failure" (see last CLI log)...

### CLI output

- `dig ns.example.com`

  ```
  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u5-Debian <<>> ns.example.com
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10036
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;ns.example.com.         IN      A

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  ns.example.com.  300     IN      A       10.20.0.9

  ;; Query time: 111 msec
  ;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Aug 09 16:42:06 CEST 2021
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 66
  ```

  So the name server resolves to our local IP, nice!
- `dig @10.20.0.9 NS loc.example.com`

  ```
  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u5-Debian <<>> @10.20.0.9 NS loc.example.com
  ; (1 server found)
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47653
  ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ; COOKIE: 7fa7e218d1c20f1e113b236e61113fb96c1b101d374cbde7 (good)
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;loc.example.com.                IN      NS

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  loc.example.com. 3600    IN      NS      ns.example.com.

  ;; Query time: 1 msec
  ;; SERVER: 10.20.0.9#53(10.20.0.9)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Aug 09 16:46:17 CEST 2021
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
  ```

  Our local DNS server knows that it's responsible for the sub domain
- `dig @10.20.0.9 s1.loc.example.com`

  ```
  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u5-Debian <<>> @10.20.0.9 s1.loc.example.com
  ; (1 server found)
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38039
  ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ; COOKIE: 7790b2d359140e5f04be8596611140927c7321fefc1fbbe9 (good)
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;s1.loc.example.com. IN      A

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  s1.loc.example.com. 3600 IN  A       10.20.0.1

  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
  loc.example.com. 3600    IN      NS      ns.example.com.

  ;; Query time: 1 msec
  ;; SERVER: 10.20.0.9#53(10.20.0.9)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Aug 09 16:49:54 CEST 2021
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119
  ```

  So the local DNS can resolve our local hosts
- `dig @1.1.1.1 NS loc.example.com`

  ```
  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u5-Debian <<>> @1.1.1.1 NS loc.example.com
  ; (1 server found)
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 33748
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
  ; OPT=15: 00 16 ("..")
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;loc.example.com.                IN      NS

  ;; Query time: 12 msec
  ;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Aug 09 16:51:45 CEST 2021
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
  ```

  **Here lies the problem:** CloudFlare does NOT answer to our NS record request. Why :o ?

Comment: Is it a connectivity problem? Is there any way for "1.1.1.1" to reach your nameserver? (Firewall?)

Comment: You cannot have publicly resolvable names where nameservers responsible for these names are on RFC1918 address ranges.

Comment: @Tomek but how do the big guys handle these tasks? I mean, I could just push my VPN clients the local DNS server, but this will override their DNS settings for all other domains as well...

Comment: That's exactly what my employer's VPN does when I use it. Additionaly it replaces default route which invalidates any other nameservers anyway.